# How to use Contact Data in a Journey for Dynamic Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey that send emails using dynamic content for the email signature. While the user doesn't inform about his country of current residency we use a global signature but, once the user tell us his country of current signature the email should use a specific signature depending of his country.

I have realized that the information about the country is not updated in the journey data extension so I don't know how to use the dynamic content properly because the system always send the email with the global signature.

I know that if I use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects-function I can map Salesforce fields with the updated information and I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same with the logic of dynamic content.

Can somebody help me please?

Thank you,
Anna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated on this page: [Personalization in the Journey Builder Email Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_personalization_in_the_journey_builder_send_email_activity.htm&type=5):

> Dynamic content also uses journey data, similar to personalization.

SO if you want to use contact data you cannot use Dynamic content block. You can accomplish the same thing with using AMPscript and if/then logic using a `lookup()` function

> If you are more experienced, use AMPScript for personalization. Use the %%=Lookup()=%% function to personalize an email with data not found in journey data, or contact data that has changed since the journey started.

Comment: Hi @EazyE thanks for your answer, is there a way to use AMP Script within dynamic content bloc? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this data is in Salesforce, then you can use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function but that will significantly impact processing if you are doing this at scale. If you are using the MC connector then you could just query the synchronized data extensions to populate that data in a DE within Marketing Cloud.

If you already have this data in a data extension, then you can A) Run a query to populate an additional column within your entry event DE with this data so you can just reference it in the email or B) Use the LookupRows AMPscript function to pull values from the source DE to check for values/rowCount to determine what content to present.

Reference: [**LookupRows**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/lookuprows.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't know where I should use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function or LookupRows.On the other hand, I have tried to create a query but Journeys Data Extension doesn't have primary key and if I create a new primary key field it isn't filled in and the contact doesn't enter to the journey. Could you help me please?